# Click once to open dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

Im trying to use `dialog()` and it's working, but I have to click two times for the dialog text to open. My latest test was adding `return false;` after `jQuery(this).dialog("close");`.

```js
jQuery("#divId").on('click', function() {
  jQuery("divclass").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    title: "Info",
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      close: function() {jQuery(this).dialog("close");return false;}
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You want to open dialog after second click?

Comment: No, I want my dialog to open when I click for first time :)

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the jQuery dialog should be outside the click listener.
also, if you want to open it on click event, you should change the autoOpen to false.

```
$("#divId").on('click', function() {
     $(".divclass").dialog( "open" );
});

$(".divclass").dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   title: "Info",
   width: 800,
   height: 600,
   modal: true,
   buttons: {
   close: function() {$(this).dialog("close");return false;}
 }
});
```